# Optimizing for loops in google apps script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexing, google-apps-script, vlookup

I am using for loops to search through large sheets (approximately 4500 rows). 
Most of them look something like this:

```
function lookup(value) {
  var tables=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Name");
  var columnvalues = tables.getRange(1, 1,tables.getLastRow()).getValues(); 
  var searchResult = columnvalues.findIndex(value); //Row Index - 1
}
 Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i].toString().indexOf(search) > -1 ) return i;

  return -1;
}
```

The app script currently runs relatively slowly. I am looking for a way to either speed up my current code or for another search method. I've been thinking about using the google spreadsheet lookup functions (index-match, vLookup) but I haven't found a way to access those functions in apps script. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

currently you wont find a way to do this faster with apps script. you have to get the entire column and search one by one like you are already doing.

the alternative you mention using sheet formulas can be flacky as you might find that the cell formulas dont inmediately update results as you change values.

the only case i can see this being sped up is if you need to make multiple search calls. in that case it will be faster to pass search terms as an array and search them all at once in the single loop.

Answer (score 0):

As you are searching a single column something a bit simpler might be a bit faster.

```
function lookup(value) {
  var searchResult = false;
  if(value == "") return;
  var tables=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Name");
  var columnvalues = tables.getRange(1, 1,tables.getLastRow()).getValues(); 
  for (var i=0; i<columnvalues.length; i++) {
    if(columnvalues[i][0] == value) {
      searchResult = i;  //Row Index - 1
      break;
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way that I have found of searching through an array is using the .filter() method of an array.

```
var yourData = range.getValues();
var results = yourData.filter(function(val) { 
    return val[0] == search ||
     val[0].includes(search);
});
//now you have a 2d array of results
```

Modify that such that it is the range you want(sorry, on mobile) and that is the fastest way that I found. Avoiding the For-Loop is the best.  You could also use a .forEach()